# Converting an algorithmic expression into a binary tree c#

Tags: c#, algorithm, binary-tree

to give you some context what I'm trying to achieve is an algorithmic formula builder that generates the values of variables (such as [a], [b], [c]), apply rules and ranges to them, then process an answer ([e]) from a formula given.

Most of this is already working, however I'm stuck at getting a algorithmic expression converted into a binary tree. I'm currently reading in values from an input field and breaking down the individual characters (excluding the brackets):

String (a+b)/(c/d) --> | a | | + | | b | | c | | / | | d | | / |

Each of these nodes are being saved with an id (auto-incremented by 1 per character) and saved in a List. They are currently being created with the right id to implement an in-order traversal.. but for the life of me I just can't understand how to build the tree.

Here's how I started:

```
public void GenerateAlgoTree()
{
    // get root node (should be the last one in the list)
    root = nodeList[nodeList.Count-1];

    // iterate through the list to find its children and set them as left and right
    List<Node> tempList = new List<Node>();
    foreach (Node n in nodeList)
    {
        tempList.Add(n);
    }

    tempList.Remove(root);
    List<Node> currentNodes = new List<Node>();
    currentNodes.Add(root);
    List<Node> nextNodes = new List<Node>();

    while (tempList.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (Node cN in currentNodes)
        {
         //recursive check for null left node??????
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: I suggest that you look into [recursive descent parsing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser)

Comment: Use a proper parser (usually defined using some variant of BNF); with the right tools this gives you a complete hierarchical AST (abstract syntax tree) out of the box. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/129965/The-Whole-Shebang-Building-your-own-general-purpos

Comment: Can you use reverse polish notation? ( a b + c d / / ) It's a lot easier to parse. Otherwise you have to implement some kind of grammar (BNF). It probably depends on what exactly you want to be able to do. BNF grammars can build compilers but that may be overkill in your case.